# how can i append part of a table based on how many tr it has?

Tags: jquery

I want to append the `"<a></a>"` content of a table , if that table is not displaying a pre-determined amount of tr's , possible ?

I set up a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/e2n57z97/4/

Any tables found on the page that DO NOT have 10 table rows , will get their `"<a></a>"` appended to the new table. All tables that have 10 tr's will not be appended.

Example HTML below showing 10 and 5 tr's , so how can i append all `"<a></a>"` info of any table that isn't showing exactly 10 tr's

```
<table class="report">  <!--  TABLE WITH 10 TR DO NOT APPEND A TAG INFO -->
    <caption>
      <span>
        <a href="#">DO NOT APPEND ME</a>
      </span>
    </caption>
    <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table class="report">  <!--  TABLE WITH LESS THEN 10 TR APPEND A TAG INFO -->
    <caption>
      <span>
        <a href="#">APPEND ME TO NEW TABLE</a>
      </span>
    </caption>
    <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


<table class="homepagemodule report" id="Starting_Lineup" align="center" cellspacing="1">
<caption><span>No Starting Lineup</span></caption>
<tbody>
APPEND INFO HERE
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will loop over all report tables and count the table rows. If there are not exact 10 rows, it appends the all links to the lineup table.

I guess you should add a class to the link and check for that link in the `.find("a")`. The current code would find all links in the report table and not just one.

```
jQuery(".report").each(function(index, element){
    if(jQuery(this).find("tr").length !== 10 && jQuery(this).attr("id") !== "Starting_Lineup"){
        var target = jQuery("#Starting_Lineup").find("tbody");
        jQuery(this).find("a").each(function(){
            target.append("<tr><td>" + jQuery(this)[0].outerHTML + "</td></tr>");
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: I need to add a $get call to this , $.get('http://%HOST%/%YEAR%/options?L=%LEAGUEID%&O=06', function (data)  , how can i incorporate that into what you have done ?

Comment: Plesse ask  a new  question for handling  of  get requests with jQuery. Do not use the comments for new  questions.